# Unable to upload file using curl

Tags: php, curl

I need upload a file using php. I have the following code that I am using

```
<?php
  $file = realpath('hello_world.jpg');
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.newocr.com/v1/upload?key=*My key*');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@'.$file));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $result;
  curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

On executing I get the error msg

> {"status":"error","message":"File must be uploaded.
>   https://www.newocr.com/api/"}

But when I manually make a form and upload the image using `multipart` it works fine. Is something wrong with my code or the issue is with the API

Executing it from command line like this

```
curl -X POST -F "file=@hello_world.jpg" http://api.newocr.com/v1/upload?key=*my api key*
```

Works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, it is giving:

404 Page Not Found
The page you are looking for could not be found. Check the address bar to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else fails, you can visit our home page at the link below.

Visit the Home Page

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Solution:

```
<?php
    $result = exec('curl -H "Expect:" -F file=@'.realpath($file).' http://api.newocr.com/v1/upload?key=KEY');
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    return $result;
?>
```